# In Splunk, How to use parsed time to determine duration between events?

Tags: eval, splunk, strptime

I have a log file that records the start and finish times for processing files. The entries contain strings that look like this:

```
=============== STARTED PROCESSING FILE filename at Thu Jul 19 00:03:55 2018 EDT===============
=============== FINISHED PROCESSING FILE filename at Thu Jul 19 00:04:05 2018 EDT===============
```

Initially I came up with a query using _time:

```
processing.log "FINISHED PROCESSING FILE" OR "STARTED PROCESSING FILE" | rex field=_raw "(?<filename>\S*)" | stats count first(_time) as start last(_time) as finished by filename | eval duration = abs( finished - start)
```

That seemed to work just fine until I realized that _time of finished and start could be hours apart even though actual processing to 10 seconds (as in the above example. So now I am trying this query:

```
processing.log "FINISHED PROCESSING FILE" OR "STARTED PROCESSING FILE" | rex field=_raw "(?<filename>\S*) at (?<ptime>.*) EDT" | eval stime=strptime(ptime,'%a %B %d %Y %H:%M:%S')| stats count first(stime) as start last(stime) as finished by filename | eval duration = abs( finished - start)
```

However it is not providing the desired results of showing the processing duration of each filename. What am I doing wrong/how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `...| stats count first(stime) as start last(stime) as finished by filename |eval duration = abs( finished - start)` try `... | stats count range(stime) as duration by filename`